# Using input object in child iframe override parent rule to open link in that iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i'm building a HTML GUI for a HVAC plant.
The parent page is basically a menu with links, the children page are a set of input object to modify a bunch of parameters.
Every link in the parent page opens a child page in an iframe

```
<a href='/admin/offset.html'target="frame">
```

If i modify a parameter inside the child page

```
<input class="single"id="SET_ON_INV_333">°C</input>
```

when i click to a different child by menu in parent page, the new child page is opened in a new tab, instead the existing iframe.
If i want to restore the wanted behaviour, i have to refresh the parent page.
Any suggestion to keep url open in the setted Iframe? Thanks
edit: to use the input within my page, i've written some code in jquery

```
var delay = (function(){
        var timer = 200;return function(callback, ms){
            clearTimeout (timer);timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);}
            ;})();
    function setCgiSingle(a){
        name=a.attr("id"),
        t=a.val(),
        w=set_cgi+"?name="+name+"&value="+t,
        $.ajax({url:w,cache:!1})
        };
    $('body').on("keyup", ".array", function () {
    var elem = $(this);
        delay(function(){
            var value=elem.val();
            value=value*10;
            elem.val(value);
            setCgiSingle(elem);
            elem.blur();},1000);
    });
```

Basically, i take the value of the input and sending via ajax call

Comment: `<input></input>`? Do you know what you’re doing there? Anyway, I cannot reproduce this issue. With `<iframe name="frame"/>` as the iFrame, `<a href="http://example.org/" target="frame">Test</a>` etc. as the test links, it works as expected in Firefox 47.0a2.

Comment: This may be an obvious question - but why not just use something like Angular if you want to dynamically load HTML into a single page and have organized data bindings? It sounds like what you are trying to do via iFrames is going to make your task far more difficult to manage and far more fragile.

Comment: I have not used angular js yet. i've used iframe only to keep the same written code (the menu in all pages) in a parent page and the different code for every single child page. All of there are contained in a PLC webserver, so no php allowed